# MySQL rounding off float value internally to one decimal place

Tags: mysql, decimal

I have a mysql database with a table X having float unsigned column amount.

The value is saved properly with two decimal places when the value is less than 10000.

But for data more than that it is rounding off two decimal places to one.

I am not sure if >10000 is causing this but thats the primary suspect.

The value is being mapped to Float amount in the application entity.

I don't know why numbers are getting rounded off for some amount values.

Did anyone face similar issue?

Comment: That's kinda what float does see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html if you want exact values use decimal.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much the definition of FLOAT. Perhaps you were wanting DECIMAL.

Comment: Yeah looks like when it is more than six digit it doesn't keep the number beyond 6 digits rather makes it 0 or truncates it in case its decimal values.Why specifically it only allows 6 digits is something we dont know for sure.
ideally we are going for decimal from float ,but still the pattern is unclear.

Comment: The rounding behavior might be due to the limitations of the `FLOAT` data type, which is a binary floating-point representation. You should consider using the `DECIMAL` data type instead of `FLOAT`. The `DECIMAL` type allows you to specify the exact precision and scale (number of decimal places) for your data.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL performs rounding when storing values according to the length of Float column. The quick fix is to set the length of the Float column in your MySql table e.g. FLOAT(11,2)

MySQL reference can be found here: [Floating-Point Types (Approximate Value)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is essentially hardcoded to round FLOAT values that are longer than 6 digits. See the comment from  Alexey Kopytov on this bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87794

> MySQL uses the FLT_DIG constant (which equals to 6 with IEEE 754
> encoding) to print float-type numbers. FLT_DIG is the number of
> decimal digits that can be converted to a float-type binary number and
> back without loss of precision for *any* input number. That doesn't
> mean there are no numbers with more significant digits that can be
> represented precisely in the binary format (and your case is an
> example of such a number), but the constant ensures that property for
> all inputs.
>
> An equivalent constant for double-type numbers is called DBL_DIG and
> equals 15 with IEEE 754 encoding. Conversion of double-type numbers
> from decimal representation to binary and back are handled by the dtoa
> library. The library allows precisely converting inputs longer than
> DBL_DIG digits for those numbers where such conversion is possible.
> Unfortunately, the library operates only with the double-type numbers,
> there's no float-type version.
>
> Going back to your examples, they are a combination of two things:
>
> - the input numbers have more than FLT_DIG precision, for which rounding to binary and converting back to decimal representation is
>   possible, but is not guaranteed.
> - MySQL converts float-type numbers to double-type in all calculations. That's why (value + 0), MIN(value) and MAX(value) result
>   in more precise decimal representations -- dtoa prints
>   double-precision numbers in those cases, so it is safe to print at
>   least 15 decimal digits.
>
> My recommendation would be to avoid the FLOAT data type entirely, or
> be ready to deal with anomalies like the one demonstrated here. The
> DOUBLE data type does not only provide higher precision, but is also
> more consistent in cases like this.